# How to calculate this inside triangle angle?

Tags: triangles, angle

Is it possible to calculate the angle X, without knowing the upper angle value for blue triangle?

[image]

Comment: Could it be that the black and the blue triangle are supposed to be similar?

Comment: @Ramanujan If the triangles were similar, the hypotenuse of both triangles would overlap. This is clearly not the case, demonstrated by the diagram (unless the diagram is misleading). Further, this would necessitate that $X = 45^\circ$.

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer is correct, they are not similar, the somewhat bold drawing at the top of the triangle is a little confusing, but the blue line there splits the black triangle's top angle in two, but no way (I know of) to determine the angles, otherwise X would be simple to calculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is impossible with the given information because there are infinite possible blue triangles in the black triangle.

Consider the following diagram, for example.

[image]

New information, however, such as the side lengths of the blue triangle, could allow one to compute $X$.

Comment: I figured, thank you for the clarification.